# Algorithm that reduces an array of integers to a single value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of integers.

Inside the `for loop`, firstly, I'm making a copy of the `initial array` to a `new array`. Then the last element is being removed and the rest elements are being rotated by one to the right.

That means the `element at index 0` will go to `index 1`, and so on, and `the element` will go to `index 0`.

At this point, I am facing the issue. The previous result has to be a source for the subsequent iteration.

The `process continues` until there's `only one element left` in the array.

Here is the code I have:

```
        int[] arr= {1,2,3,4,5}; // orignal array

        int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];
        int[] result = new int[newArr.length];
        for(int i = 1;i<n;i++)
        {

            newArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length - i);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));// here i am deleting one array at last,
// code works fine upto here. but i want the next step as below commented code to perform in loop. which i am really unable to do.

            //System.arraycopy(newArr, 0, result, 1, newArr.length - 1);
            //result[0] = newArr[newArr.length - 1];
            //result = Arrays.copyOf(result,result.length-1);
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        }
```

**output** should come like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // original array

[1, 2, 3, 4] // array after deletion

[4, 1, 2, 3] // array after rotaion

[4, 1, 2]// again after deletion from previous array

[2, 4, 1]// array after rotaion

[2, 4]// again after deletion from previous array

[4, 2]// array after rotation

[4]

final answer is 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will `perform much better` if you `get rid of` these `intermediate arrays`. If you have a few million elements in the array, your algorithm will require to allocate in memory a few million arrays which doesn't sound very performance-wise. From the clean-coding point of view, `only one defensive copy is needed` to preserve the source array intact. And the `required operations will be done in place`.

The core of this algorithm is the variable **`len`** defined inside the method **`rotateAndDelete()`**, which denotes the boundary of the `"current array"`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(rotateAndDelete(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
    }
```

```
    public static int rotateAndDelete(int[] source) {
        int len = source.length;
        int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(source, len);
        while (len > 1) {
            len--; // deletion in-place - the last valid index becomes less by one
            rotate(copy, len);
        }
        return copy[0];
    }
```

```
    private static void rotate(int[] arr, int len) {
        int first = arr[len - 1];
        // shift all elements to the right
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
        }
        arr[0] = first;
    }
```

**output**

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer solved my issue. I am still in learning phase. will definetly brush up my coding skills. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend doing everything in a single method. Start by writing a method to perform the rotation. I would name it `rotate` and it might look something like

```
private static void rotate(int[] arr) {
    int v = arr[arr.length - 1];
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[0] = v;
}
```

Then you can use that and a loop to express the algorithm you described

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
// While there are more than one elements
while (arr.length > 1) {
    // Print the elements
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // Remove the last element from the array
    arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length - 1);
    // Rotate the array
    rotate(arr);
}
// Only one value left
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
while (arr.length > 1) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    arr = deleteAndRotate(arr);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4]
```

- return array if length == 1.
- create a new array of one less size
- store next to last item in first position
- fill remainder of new array starting with old.
- return new array.

```
public static int[] deleteAndRotate(int[] v) {
    if (v.length == 1) {
        return v;
    }
    int[] r = new int[v.length-1];
    r[0] = v[v.length-2];
    
    System.arraycopy(v, 0, r, 1, v.length-2);
    return r;
}
```